# Is this plant with small white blossoms a weed or a flower?

Tags: identification, flowers, weeds

There is a plant growing beneath our wine. What kind of plant is it? Flower or weed? Five little leafs are on the white blossoms. It is growing very fast. Leaves are large and heart shaped.

[image: Mystery flower]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's **[buckwheat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckwheat)** from the [fagopyrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagopyrum) family (I would expect some reddish tinge especially on the lower stem for buckwheat - but your photos only show the tips).

Whether you consider it a flower or a weed is up to you - beauty is in the eye of the beholder. I have it amongst other annuals in my wildflower / insect food border and it self-seeds well. Note that most [polygonaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonaceae) tend to proliferate (and hence are typically seen as weed), so you *might* want to cut it before it goes to seed. But it's quite controllable by ripping out seedlings, unlike thistles etc.

Comment: I would consider it like a weed, just because it shadows the wine grape.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi that depends on the number - one or two certainly aren't a problem as buckwheat isn't exactly a dense plant. Mostly a thin stem and a few leaves here and there.